# 403 forbidden error loading "sites" files

Tags: 7, files

I had an installation of Drupal 7.24 and I was doing a new install with 7.26. Everything went well until the end, when I tried to login. When I try to login or submit any form the page just refreshes back to where I was.

I inspected element to see what was going on and noticed a bunch of files from `site/default/...` were returning 403 forbidden. I chmod-ed all the files in `sites/default` to `777` to try it out and it still did the same thing.

What part of Drupal could this problem reside in?

EDIT:
deleted cookie,
fore refreshed,
tried in incognito.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out if you have set the public &/or private file permission on configuration page > Media > File System.
Also do check permission of what ever form your are trying to submit.

Comment: check if .htaccess is configured correctly